# Loading fonts in LuaTeX (plain TeX)

Tags: fonts, luatex, plain-tex

I am trying to understand how fonts work with (plain) LuaTeX.

I use the standard ConTeXt suite, and I made a luatex-plain format using the file *luatex-plain.tex* from the distribution:

```
luatex --ini luatex-plain.tex
```

If I define this file (foo.tex)

```
\font\test=cmbx10
\test NZQRC
\bye
```

It compiles okay with

```
luatex --fmt=luatex-plain.fmt foo.tex
```

The same also works with TrueType fonts.

But if I use the *msbm10* font ("blackboard"), I get:

```
!LuaTeX error (file msbm10): Font msbm10 at 72 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

If I add the `\starttext ... \stoptext` and compile it using `context` instead of `luatex`, it works all right.

So, at this point I am quite puzzled. 
How can I use the msbm10 font in plain LuaTeX?

**Edit:** The problem was that I was using luatex from a ConTeXt installation. With luatex from TeXlive, it works all right. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Note: you are not using "plain", but something that is related to ConTeXt. `luatex-plain.tex` is only in the ConTeXt distribution, and it surely has a very special way of dealing with fonts. If you really want plain TeX, then use plain TeX. Just call

```
luatex foo.tex
```

and you are fine. Even with the `msbm10` font.

If this answer is not what you are looking for, please write what you want to achieve.